# Flutter web custom hinting text editing controller issue: duplicate characters after adding text following hint insertion

Tags: flutter

I have implemented a simple, incomplete suggestion component that resembles the suggestions you see in IDEs like Copilot. Most of the functionality has been implemented, but there's a very strange phenomenon.

Here is a screenshot demonstrating the functionality of this component (including the error). Please note that in the GIF below, when the TextField provides a suggestion, I input '2', but the actual TextField duplicates it as '22'.

[image]

I understand that this problem is quite challenging, as it's rather vague and requires reading and understanding the code.

You can directly copy and run the following code.

flutter sdk: '>=3.1.2 <4.0.0'
It only occurs on the Flutter web side. It works normally on Android.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Debouncer {
  final int milliseconds;
  Timer? _timer;

  Debouncer({required this.milliseconds});

  run(VoidCallback action) {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), action);
  }

  void cancel() {
    _timer?.cancel();
  }
}

class CustomTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  bool hinting = false;
  bool isEditingHint = false;

  int? hintStartIndex;
  int? hintEndIndex;

  int? lastEditLength;
  int? lastEditIndex;

  CustomTextEditingController() {
    addListener(_cursorListener);
    addListener(_contentListener);
  }

  int? _cursorPreviousCursorIndex;
  int? _cursorPreviousLength;
  String _cursorPreviousText = "";

  void _cursorListener() {
    int currentCursorIndex = selection.baseOffset;
    String currentText = text;
    int currentLength = currentText.length;

    if (isEditingHint) {
      _cursorPreviousCursorIndex = currentCursorIndex;
      _cursorPreviousLength = currentLength;
      _cursorPreviousText = currentText;
      return;
    }
    if (!hinting) {
      _cursorPreviousCursorIndex = currentCursorIndex;
      _cursorPreviousLength = currentLength;
      _cursorPreviousText = currentText;
      return;
    }
    if (currentText != _cursorPreviousText) {
      _cursorPreviousCursorIndex = currentCursorIndex;
      _cursorPreviousLength = currentLength;
      _cursorPreviousText = currentText;
      return;
    }

    if (currentCursorIndex == -1) {
      _cursorPreviousCursorIndex = currentCursorIndex;
      _cursorPreviousLength = currentLength;
      _cursorPreviousText = currentText;
      return;
    }

    if (currentCursorIndex == lastEditIndex) {
      _cursorPreviousCursorIndex = currentCursorIndex;
      _cursorPreviousLength = currentLength;
      _cursorPreviousText = currentText;
      return;
    }

    int r = Random().nextInt(1000);
    print("------_cursorListener$r------");
    print(
        "Called _cursorListener() method currentCursorIndex $currentCursorIndex currentText $currentText currentLength $currentLength");

    print("Start processing data changes");
    print("Previous cursor position [$lastEditIndex] && hint end position [$hintEndIndex]");
    if (currentCursorIndex > hintStartIndex! && currentCursorIndex < hintEndIndex!) {
      print("Hint content is selected, applyHint");
      applyHint();
    } else if (currentLength == lastEditLength) {
      print("Text remains unchanged, cursor moves, deleting hint Current text length $currentLength Concatenated length $currentLength");
      deleteHint();
    }

    _cursorPreviousLength = currentLength;
    _cursorPreviousText = currentText;
    _cursorPreviousCursorIndex = currentCursorIndex;
    print("------_cursorListener$r------");
  }

  int? _contentPreviousLength;
  String _contentPreviousText = "";

  void _contentListener() {
    print("Current cursor position: [${selection.baseOffset}], Current text content: [$text]");

    String currentText = text;
    int currentLength = currentText.length;
    int currentCursorIndex = selection.baseOffset;

    if (isEditingHint) {
      _contentPreviousLength = currentLength;
      _contentPreviousText = currentText;
      return;
    }
    if (!hinting) {
      _contentPreviousLength = currentLength;
      _contentPreviousText = currentText;
      return;
    }

    if (currentText.isEmpty) {
      _contentPreviousLength = currentLength;
      _contentPreviousText = currentText;
      return;
    }

    if (currentText == _contentPreviousText) {
      _contentPreviousLength = currentLength;
      _contentPreviousText = currentText;
      return;
    }
    int r = Random().nextInt(1000);

    print("------_contentListener$r------");

    print("Called _contentListener() method  currentText [$currentText] currentLength [$currentLength]");

    print("previousText.length ${_contentPreviousText.length} currentText.length ${currentText.length}");
    if (_contentPreviousLength! > currentLength) {
      // If the previous text length is greater than the current text length, it means a deletion has occurred
      for (int i = 0; i < _contentPreviousText.length; i++) {
        if (i >= currentText.length || _contentPreviousText[i] != currentText[i]) {
          // Find the first different character position, which is the position of the deletion
          print("Character deletion occurred Character [${_contentPreviousText[i]}] at [$i] deleted");
          print("Previous text: [$_contentPreviousText] Text after deletion: [$currentText]");

          if (i < hintStartIndex!) {
            hintStartIndex = hintStartIndex! - 1;
            hintEndIndex = hintEndIndex! - 1;
            deleteHint();
          }
          if (i >= hintStartIndex! && i < hintEndIndex!) {
            hintEndIndex = hintEndIndex! - 1;
            deleteHint();
          }
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (_contentPreviousLength! < currentLength) {
      // If the previous text length is less than the current text length, it means an addition has occurred
      for (int i = 0; i < currentText.length; i++) {
        if (i >= _contentPreviousText.length || _contentPreviousText[i] != currentText[i]) {
          // Find the first different character position, which is the position of the addition
          print("Character addition occurred, i [$i] previous character:${_contentPreviousText[i]} current character ${currentText[i]}");
          print("Before character addition: [$_contentPreviousText] After character addition: [$currentText]");

          if (i <= hintStartIndex!) {
            hintStartIndex = hintStartIndex! + 1;
            hintEndIndex = hintEndIndex! + 1;
            print("Content has changed, deleting hint");
            deleteHint();
          }
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    lastEditLength = currentLength;
    lastEditIndex = currentCursorIndex;
    _contentPreviousText = currentText;
    _contentPreviousLength = currentLength;
    print("------_contentListener$r------");
  }

  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan({required BuildContext context, TextStyle? style, required bool withComposing}) {
    style = style ?? const TextStyle();
    List<TextSpan> spans = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      TextStyle currentStyle = style;
      if (hintStartIndex != null && hintEndIndex != null) {
        if (i >= hintStartIndex! && i <= hintEndIndex!) {
          currentStyle = style.copyWith(color: Colors.grey);
        }
      }
      spans.add(TextSpan(text: text[i], style: currentStyle));
    }
    return TextSpan(style: style, children: spans);
  }

  void appendHint(int index, String hint) {
    int r = Random().nextInt(1000);
    print("==================appendHint$r==================");

    print("Called appendHint() method, appended hint");
    deleteHint();

    isEditingHint = true;
    hinting = true;

    int currentCursorIndex = selection.baseOffset;
    String hintTempText = insertAtPositionString(text, hint, index);

    print("Content to be added to text: [$hintTempText]");

    int cursorIndex = currentCursorIndex;

    hintStartIndex = index;
    hintEndIndex = index + hint.length - 1;
    print("Hint starts at $hintStartIndex, hint ends at $hintEndIndex");

    lastEditLength = hintTempText.length;
    lastEditIndex = cursorIndex;

    print("Content before appending hint: $text");
    text = hintTempText;
    print("Content after appending hint: $text");

    print("Set new content, reset cursor to $cursorIndex");
    selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: cursorIndex);

    isEditingHint = false;

    print("appendHint finished, result after appending: $text");

    print("==================appendHint$r==================");
  }

  void applyHint() {
    int r = Random().nextInt(1000);
    print("==================applyHint$r==================");

    print("Called applyHint() method");

    isEditingHint = true;
    print("Applied hint, hinting: [$hinting]");

    hintStartIndex = null;
    hintEndIndex = null;
    notifyListeners();

    hinting = false;
    isEditingHint = false;

    print("==================applyHint$r==================");
  }

  void deleteHint() {
    if (hintStartIndex == null || hintEndIndex == null) {
      return;
    }
    int r = Random().nextInt(1000);
    print("==================deleteHint$r==================");

    isEditingHint = true;

    String currentText = text;
    int currentCursorIndex = selection.baseOffset;
    int currentLength = currentText.length;

    String endString = "";
    if (hintEndIndex! + 1 != currentLength) {
      endString = text.substring(hintEndIndex! + 1, currentLength);
    }
    int cursorIndex = currentCursorIndex;

    String deleteTempText = text.substring(0, hintStartIndex!) + endString;
    print("Text to be set by deleteHint [$deleteTempText]");

    if (currentCursorIndex > hintEndIndex!) {
      cursorIndex -= hintEndIndex! - hintStartIndex! + 1;
    } else if (cursorIndex > deleteTempText.length) {
      cursorIndex = text.length;
    }
    if (cursorIndex < 0) {
      cursorIndex = 0;
    }

    lastEditLength = deleteTempText.length;
    lastEditIndex = cursorIndex;

    print("Content before deletion [$text]");
    text = deleteTempText;
    print("Content after deletion [$text]");
    selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: cursorIndex);
    print("Content deleted, cursor reset to tmpCursorIndex: [$cursorIndex]");

    hintStartIndex = null;
    hintEndIndex = null;

    hinting = false;
    isEditingHint = false;

    print("Deletion finished, result: $text");

    print("==================deleteHint$r==================");
  }

  String insertAtPositionString(String original, String insertText, int position) {
    if (position < 0 || position > original.length) {
      throw ArgumentError('Invalid insertion position provided.');
    }
    return original.substring(0, position) + insertText + original.substring(position);
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final CustomTextEditingController controller = CustomTextEditingController();
  late int currentCursorIndex;
  int? previousCursorIndex;
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(() {
      currentCursorIndex = controller.selection.baseOffset;

      if (!controller.hinting && !controller.isEditingHint && controller.text.isNotEmpty) {

          debouncer.run(() {
            print("Ran the timer to create a hint");
            controller.appendHint(currentCursorIndex, "test hint");
          });

      }

      previousCursorIndex = currentCursorIndex;
    });
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (focusNode.hasFocus) {
        currentCursorIndex = controller.selection.baseOffset;
      }
    });
  }

  Debouncer debouncer = Debouncer(milliseconds: 3000);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Column(children: [
              TextField(
                controller: controller,
                focusNode: focusNode,
                onChanged: (s) {},
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.appendHint(currentCursorIndex, "test hint");
                  },
                  child: Text("Append")),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.applyHint();
                  },
                  child: Text("Apply"))
            ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Log:

```
Current cursor position: [0], Current text content: []
Current cursor position: [1], Current text content: [1]
Current cursor position: [1], Current text content: [1]
Ran the timer to create a hint
==================appendHint535==================
Called appendHint() method, appended hint
Content to be added to text: [1test hint]
Hint starts at 1, hint ends at 9
Content before appending hint: 1
Content after appending hint: 1test hint
Set new content, reset cursor to 1
appendHint finished, result after appending: 1test hint
==================appendHint535==================
Current cursor position: [2], Current text content: [12test hint]
------_contentListener748------
Called _contentListener() method  currentText [12test hint] currentLength [11]
previousText.length 10 currentText.length 11
Character addition occurred, i [1] previous character:t current character 2
Before character addition: [1test hint] After character addition: [12test hint]
Content has changed, deleting hint
==================deleteHint412==================
DeleteHint will set text to [12]
Content before deletion [12test hint]
Current cursor position: [-1], Current text content: [12]
Current cursor position: [0], Current text content: [12]
Content after deletion [12]
Content deleted, cursor reset to tmpCursorIndex: [2]
Deletion finished, result: 12
==================deleteHint412==================
------_contentListener748------
Current cursor position: [3], Current text content: [122] // Please pay attention to this log line. It's very strange; it seems to have changed its content to "12344" on its own.
```

In this log, "==================deleteHint412==================" will have a corresponding "==================deleteHint412==================". This means that this is a log generated during the execution of a certain method. Since the execution of the method triggers a listener and results in nesting, this approach makes the log clearer.

Problem Description:

I have a custom text editing controller in my Flutter app. I'm trying to implement a hint system, where hints are inserted and removed based on user input. Initially, I enter "123", and the input field displays:

```
123
```

Then, a hint "test hint" is provided, and the input field becomes:

```
123test hint
```

Next, I input '4', and the expected behavior is that the input field should display:

```
1234
```

However, the actual result is:

```
12344
```

Clearly, the TextField inputted "4" multiple times, causing the result to become "12344."

This error appears to be related to certain underlying logic of the flutter web TextField component.

I strongly suspect it's an issue with the focus in Flutter web; the focus logic in Flutter web is very different from that in Android.

Comment: This issue only occurs in Flutter web; I believe it's a bug specific to Flutter web.